Why does shreemat bhagvatam padam puran ghord puran narad puran said that vyas appear before shree ram
In shreemat bhagvat mahapurana padam puran ghord puran narad puran said that vyas appear before shree ram why does these puran said this because vyas appear in treatayuga
